# Is there a [mooc] about tag burnination?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I recently encountered the [mooc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mooc) tag. Virtually all of the questions were either "please help me with my homework for my MOOC" or "how do I use this MOOC web site?" questions.

The first type is a Meta tag that is comparable to the old [homework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag; the fact that the question is about an assignment for the OP's MOOC tells us nothing about the actual topic of the question.

The second type of question ("how do I use this MOOC software?") isn't even on-topic here because it's about general computing, not programming.

The tag was under 50 questions (38 questions originally if I remember correctly), so I did some initial cleanup after consulting a 20k user. Are there any objections at this point to completing the rest of this burnination?

Comment: "Please don't clean them all up by yourself" is the only objection I have right now...they may need to be edited/closed/etc and it'd be good to keep track of that.

Comment: "Oy [mooc]! Fooc off", but I think that edit would be reverted in a second...

Comment: while i have no objection regarding to tag but question surely seems horrible

Comment: I think that if you found a pile of garbage, you can only dive in. BTW, all questions with this tag are closed. Maybe when roomba runs this would be considered status-complete.

Comment: "The tag [mooc] - ow!"